# Accessing memer fields once casting is done

Tags: c, pointers, structure

is it possible to cast a structure pointer to a character pointer and then be able to access the fields of a struct with the char pointer, like the ff?
`struct student {int id; char *p;}` and then `struct student *s_stud ={{13,"jacob"},{12,"lia"}}`
`char *stud = (char *) s_stud` and then be able to do sth like `(*(stud+i))->id`

Comment: Please add the language tag and expand the code into a [mre] - it's really hard to understand the question as it is right now. Or what you are even trying to do

Comment: If this is C or a C-like language then `(*(stud+i))->id` would simply not compile because `stud` is a `char*` - and that does not have any `id` member

Comment: please always remember to tag the language. your questions will get no views at all if you fail to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use the `offsetof` macro, included from `stddef.h` (iirc).

So you can cast a struct pointer to a char pointer, then offsetof into where the actual char pointer you want is.

Example: `char* target_string = struct_ptr + offsetof(struct your_struct, name_of_charptr_you_want)`

You cannot access the struct members from the new char pointer. That is unless you keep using `offsetof` to access them.